# BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Tags: python, pip

Getting the first line of `pip freeze` is fine:

```
$ pip freeze | head -1
awscli==1.27.11
```

But doing some with `pip list` causes an error:

```
$ pip list | head -1
Package               Version
ERROR: Pipe to stdout was broken
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Why does this error occur with `pip list` but not occur with `pip freeze`?

Comment: I just did some more digging, and what I really wonder is why you don't get the error from both. I got the same error with a dummy program just doing `for i in range(10000): print(i)` when I pipe it into head. But looking at the source code for `pip freeze`, (https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/main/src/pip/_internal/commands/freeze.py) I don't see anything that explains how it avoids getting the same error. I was half expecting to find a try/except in there, but it's a plain loop of calls to `sys.stdout.write()`, which should produce the same error by my understanding.